# First.Value of LinkedList is null but linked list is not empty

Tags: c#, linked-list, null, nullreferenceexception

I am programming a console game but I get an error on trying to use LinkedList.First.Value as it returns null. However, the list is not empty as I set so that the first entry is 55.

```
 LinkedList<int> Pos = new LinkedList<int>();
```

Main :

```
var p = new Program();
        p.Pos.AddFirst(55);
        Timer myTimer = new Timer();
        myTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(Move);
        myTimer.Interval = 1000;
        myTimer.Start();
```

Error Causing code (Move):

```
p.Pos.AddFirst(p.Pos.First.Value + p.dir);
```

> System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an
> instance of an object.'
>
> System.Collections.Generic.LinkedList.First.get returned null.

Full code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Timers;
using System.Collections;

namespace Snake
{
    class Program
    {
        LinkedList<int> Pos = new LinkedList<int>();
        int dir = 1;
        bool snakeAlive = true;
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var p = new Program();
            p.Pos.AddLast(55);
            Timer myTimer = new Timer();
            myTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(Move);
            myTimer.Interval = 1000; // 1000 ms is one second
            myTimer.Start();
            do
            {
                switch (Console.ReadKey().Key)
                {
                    case ConsoleKey.UpArrow:
                        p.dir = -10;
                        break;
                    case ConsoleKey.DownArrow:
                        p.dir = 10;
                        break;
                    case ConsoleKey.LeftArrow:
                        p.dir = -1;
                        break;
                    case ConsoleKey.RightArrow:
                        p.dir = 1;
                        break;
                }
            } while (p.snakeAlive == true);
        }

        void drawGame()
        {
            Console.Clear();
            for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
            {
                if (i % 10 == 9)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(IsSnake(Pos, i));
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.Write(IsSnake(Pos, i));
                }
            }
        }
        String IsSnake(LinkedList<int> sPos, int position)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < sPos.Count; i++)
            {
                if (position == sPos.ElementAt(i))
                {
                    return "==";
                }
            }
            return "[]";
        }
        public static void Move(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)  {
            var p = new Program();
                p.Pos.AddFirst(p.Pos.First.Value + p.dir);
                p.Pos.RemoveLast();
            p.drawGame();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please show a bit more context of the line that fails? Where is is called? What is p here?

Comment: all it is var p = new Program();
Its because main and elapsed Event Handler need to be static

Comment: also its called from the myTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(Move);

Comment: PLease [edit] your question to show it. If you create a `new Program()` in the event handler, its Pos list will be empty.

Comment: Ok its edited now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`var p = new Program();` in the Move event handler will create a new instance of your Program class which is not related to the instance you created before. Its `Pos` list will be empty.

You could make the `Move` method an instance methof (remove the `static`) and change the event subscription to `myTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(p.Move);`

Within the Move method you can then directly use `Pos`.

Comment: This works thanks, I haven't really wrapped my head around this whole static and instances thing